# Why can the twin plane be uncoincide with the composition plane in reflection twin?

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography

In the book Elements of X-Ray Diffraction, p67, I found the following sentence:

> In the case of a reflection twin, the composition plane may or may not coincide with the twin plane.

But I think in reflection twin, the composition plane should always coincide with the twin plane.

Can you give me an example of reflection twin in which the two planes are not coincide with each other?

Comment: Hi Alex, I think you need to add a lot more context here so that people have a better idea of what the book is talking about and what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a cubic lattice, but the motif is asymmetric. If you reflect and twin in the plane {100} you'd get something like:

[image: Twin/reflect in same plane]

Now suppose you reflect in the {100} place but twin in the {101} plane then you'd get:

[image: Twin/reflect in different planes]

This is perhaps a somewhat contrived example, but it shows how the two planes need not be identical.

I don't think you could get this in the less symmetric lattices like monoclinic or triclinic because it would be hard to match two different planes between the mirror images. If someone can come up with an example please post as I would be interested to see it.